# Counting number of times range words appears in a cell (Google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to have a formula in Google Sheets that will count the number of times a range of words appears in a specific cell. The keyword range in this example only contains 3 cells but could be expanded to contain 10+. The closest I have come was using countif, but that would not work for a range of words.[image: Example]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(1*REGEXMATCH(LOWER(SPLIT(A2, " ")), 
 "\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b", 1, LOWER(A5:A10))&"\b")))
```

[image]